# What makes an engine suitable for supersonic flight?

Tags: engine, supersonic, propulsion

I would like to know for example if someone can take the "core" of an CFM56 used on A320, redesign it by adding a supersonic intake, a convergent-divergent nozzle, and reduce its bypass ratio, but keeping the same stages of compression and turbine stages. Will it be able to achieve supersonic speeds?

Comment: The reverse: [How difficult is it to design a high bypass turbofan given a military derived core?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59913/14897)

Answer (score 21):

Yes.

This is more or less exactly what had been planned for the (now defunct) [Aerion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerion) supersonic business jet.  The engine was to be developed by GE, with the core of a CFM56, the fan replaced with a lower bypass fan, inlet and exhaust replaced, and that's it.  The core was to be off the shelf CFM56 core.

Also, the F101 and F110 fighter jet engines and the CFM56 share a very similar core.  It's not exactly the same, but it's fairly close.

Comment: Wait a minute. The [linked answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59913/14897) from @ymb1 states that the CFM56 was actually derived from the GE F101 core, with improvements fed back into the F110.

Comment: To complete this answer: the idea is simply that you do not want a supersonic flow over the compressor blades. And the inlet has to slow the flow enough that the compressor won't become supersonic.